# Calculating the amount of statically allocated memory

Tags: c, static-analysis

Given a large **C** project with multiple source files, what is an efficient way of figuring out how much statically allocated memory will it use?

In case the question is not clear enough, a good approximation for the value would be

> Σ sizeof(x), where x is an array

and can be obtained at compile time.

Comment: I think it depends on how picky you wish to be. Obviously all statics/globals have to be counted. But strictly speaking, arrays with incomplete initializer lists are statically allocated memory too, as they need to go through static initialization before program startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build it, and then use tools that inspect the resulting binary, since it will contain this information.

Which tools to use depends on the platform, on Linux you might try `nm` and/or `objdump`.